# toggle jquery show /hide first click doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Why my first click doesn´t work, the second work!

this is the code

```
$(function () {
    $("#clickme").toggle(function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({left:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({left:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/

in the jsfiddle it worked but on my page i must press 2 times?

Can anybody help me?

Comment: If it works on JSFiddle then this is not the code you need to be trying to fix right? Don't you think it's more likely that there's other code causing the problem?

Comment: Are you binding to document ready? If you're not, your results could be unpredictable!

Comment: This code works on jsfiddle but not on my machine. Guess what can be the issue. Your time starts now :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's that all your script? try set the function on document ready event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clickme").toggle(function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({left:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({left:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    });
});
```